# How to replace every occurrence of = in a string in batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, variables, return

First time post - sorry!
Yes, I have seen many posts on how to replace characters in a string in batch script, but I can't seem to make any of them work with "=". Here is what I would like to do:

This is a batch file, running in a bash shell:

```
set ss=param1=  3, pram2 =  27.3, param3  = 11,
echo %ss% | sed 's/=/ /g' |  sed 's/,/ /g'
```

it beautifully writes to the screen:

```
param1   3  pram2    27.3  param3    11
```

That is exactly what I would like a variable to be full of, not look at it on a screen! I would like it to write instead to a variable - say, something like:

```
set sss=echo %ss% | sed 's/=/ /g' |  sed 's/,/ /g'
echo %sss% returns ECHO is off.
echo $sss returns $sss
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "ss=param1=  3, pram2 =  27.3, param3  = 11,"

for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'echo %ss%^|sed "s/=/ /g"^|sed "s/,/ /g"'
) do set "sss=%%A"

echo sss: %sss%
```

In Bash, you can assign the Stdout of a command directly to a variable.

In CMD, you can use a `for /f` loop to run a command and return each line of Stdout.
The command run needs the `|` escaped with `^`.
The arguments of `sed` may require double quotes instead of single quotes that Bash may use.
The `delims=` option tells the `for` loop to not delimit each line into tokens.

View `for /?` for help about running commands in a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you Michael, your first example worked like a charm...though I need to do some more research to understand why on earth it did.

Comment: Your welcome. I updated the answer with a brief description of why CMD requires a `for` loop to capture the stdout.